# Determine the background color of an object with a clipped texture

Tags: texturing

I have a simple cube object whith a picture texture clipped, not repeated:

The background of the object (I mean, the surface that is not covered by the image) is black.

How can I change the color of this surface part (the surface that is not covered by the image) to white or another color?

[image: maped object]

[image: unwrap]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work with this setup, plug your *Image Texture* node into a *MixRGB* and use the *Alpha* output as factor:

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks. it seems simpler than other method.

Comment: I was not sure it would work but it looks like what is outside the picture is considered as alpha 0

Comment: @aitor I would suggest this as accepted answer, it is simpler and sufficient. moonboots: Yes, that's how it works  ;)

Comment: @ Gordon Brinkmann, yes of course, what could it be except alpha 0  ;)

Comment: Ok! I changed it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

you could try this node setup:

[image]

I took a very low number as threshold: 0.00001

Sorry, you cannot see that in the screenshot.